# "New answers to old questions" tool has a design bug

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools

I would suspect it was introduced recently because I go there from times to times and this just caught my attention today.

On the `table` from the main element of the [*"New Answers to Old Questions"*](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) page, there is an hardcoded `width` of `500px` set on the rows `td` and this makes the table overflow my screen.

Here is for an image that would be better than a long description:

[image: row with too big, causing a screen overflow]

PS: I am on a resolution of 1440x900 and I don't have any zoom applied on my browser for the matter at hand.

This has even got worse since I originally posted it, now, I don't even have the post info in the viewport anymore:

[image: post info outside of viewport]

Comment: How wide is your viewport? I think the site in general has a minimum usable width of some 800px.

Comment: https://whatismyviewport.com/ says 1440px. And maybe more importantly, I checked, for the sake of it, I am not zoomed in

Comment: OK, just checking to make sure you weren't for some reason on some 800x600 screen or something ancient

Comment: I can't believe this post is more than 1 year old and that's all the attention it got... This drives me crazy and makes it really annoying to review the page...

Comment: @Tomerikoo The issue doesn't seem to be reproducible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f7tM.png Maybe they just made an update in the last 2 hours?

Comment: @TylerH no, it depends on sentences. Go to some other pages and you'll see it is still there.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Looks like the question could do with editing to include some additional reproduction information. Then it can be flagged for a moderator to add [meta-tag:status-review] to it so CMs/devs will see it.

Comment: @TylerH well, that is quite frankly complex to have a way to reproduce it, the page is just a pager in a fifo list, so what is page XY now might be page ZW in the next second.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε It doesn't have to be absolute page references. You can just find a page that has it and a page that doesn't and compare the differences, if you know it is based on the contents of the post. Good bug reports include detailed reproduction steps; I went to the 10k tools page and couldn't reproduce the issue by refreshing, so more information is needed *in the question/report above*.

Comment: I know, but, quite frankly, I doubt this will be worth my time to try and reproduce it when simply dumping lorem ipsum in a dev environment would probably be enough to reproduce it already. Also it is not like there is *a* page in a million that has the bug. At the moment of writing this comment, only the page 2 out of the ten firsts did not had the bug.

Comment: @Tyler from my experience, the bug is quite random (surely it has some trigger that I'm just not aware of). Sometimes it happens and sometimes not. Refreshing sometimes helps but mostly not. I wish I had a way to reproduce it but currently the only way I can tell is go enough times to the tool and it will happen eventually...

Comment: @TylerH First time I entered this morning and [this is how I see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEBWX.png)

Answer (score 3):

I also see the same problem on a 2560x1440 display. I also noticed the `width: 500px` on the content's `td` so I ran a simple script to change that and it didn't seem to have an effect:

[image: Image showing the NATO tool page with the modified width value]

I am surely lacking CSS/HTML knowledge about this and guessing it could be related to parent attributes or just some attributes I'm unfamiliar with that override the width. Anyway I'm pretty sure the fix is simple and will be great if this can be fixed (or even if someone can just find the cause so we can fix it with a script until an official fix arrives).

---

This is the script I ran to update the `width` values of all `td` elements:

```
const natoItems = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (const item of natoItems) {
    const mainContent = item.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
    mainContent.style.width = '100px';
}
```