# "New answers to old questions" for small screens

Tags: feature-request, design, 10k-tools

The "New answers to old questions" page is actually really difficult to read on mobile screens.

The actual result looks like :

[image]

It seems that the following meta tag is not present on this page:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Is it planned to make this page compatible on small screens, or is it possible to plan it ?

At least, the default scale, even if the [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402806) indicates that the columns width seems to be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user interface has been updated and is now responsive.

[image: 10K tools responsive view]

new HTML Source:

```
<html class="html__responsive ...">
<!-- ... --->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Thanks StackOverflow :)